# Why is IR2104 MOSFET driver not working?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, frequency, mosfet-driver

I have a NE555 producing about 250 kHz that runs at 5 V. I want to control the MOSFET driver [IR2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671) with it. Here's my schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I tried reducing/increasing the frequency (from 1 kHz to 250 kHz) and tried capacitor values like 22 pF, 470 pF, 1 nF, 10 nF, 100 nF and even an electrolytic 4.7 μF capacitor.

I don't quite understand the value required for the capacitor (any calculation will be very helpful). I also tried removing the BC547 acting as a NOT gate and connecting pin 3 of the IR2104 to VCC directly as suggested by some random forums and YouTube videos.

Anyway, the ground of the NE555 is connected to the IR2104 and others as well.

The problem is that the circuit doesn't work at all. It seems all cold and dead, except when I swap the capacitor; then I see a blink of light. Am I doing something wrong or is the IR2104 dead?

Comment: Decoupling capacitor is missing. Show oscillogram of IN, VB, HO and LO.

Comment: That's the thing I ignored. Shouldn't it work without the decoupling capacitor?

Comment: In addition to the decoupling caps as winny stated, always use gate stopper resistors (from driver output to the gate) to limit the charge and discharge currents for the sake of the chip's output drivers' health. For the value of the bootstrap cap check [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/494428/103420), but generally, for frequencies above 50 kHz, 20 to 100 times the Ciss of the MOSFET is enough. IRFZ44N's Ciss is 1.5n so 100n should be alright.

Comment: The way the circuit is wired can be very critical. Add the capacitor and eliminate a potential problem.

Comment: Probably not. Why risk it?

Comment: Hi all, I connected SD to VCC, and used a 1uF and 100nF decoupling capacitors. Looks like the circuit is working! I had a final blow - the 104 disc capacitor I used came dead as confirmed by the meter (when I used other caps seems like I didn't connect SD to VCC) and most of the 104 are 65nF - 80nF. Thanks all for the deep insight in comments and good answer.

Comment: Please post your last comment as an answer. You don't have to mark it as the accepted answer, but comments are ephemeral in nature and tends to get deleted, whereas answers tend not to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *The problem is that the circuit doesn't work at all.*

Why does your circuit put the [IR2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671) into shutdown every time your input tries to go high? This doesn't seem at all right! You should leave the \$\overline{SD}\$ pin high to enable the chip: -

[image]

Then, if you were correctly activating the \$\overline{SD}\$ pin (which you aren't unfortunately), you'd need a base resistor adding like this: -

[image]

Without that base resistor, the \$IN\$ input can't be raised any higher than about 0.7 volts and, that won't likely activate the IR2104.

Then do all the other stuff mentioned in comments under the question.

Answer (score -1):

remove the transistor and resistor network from the input side because it will shut down the ic every half cycle and the circuit wont work

Comment: This is what Andy already stated above.